# LaTeX Listings - curly doesn't display properly

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I'm creating document using pdflatex and I have a problem with listings. Program doesn't display curly braces {} properly. They looks like this `– ”` What's the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the community with a minimal example that replicates the problem? This would include an image of your output.

Answer (score 1):

Some characters as e.g. `{` are used for internal LaTeX commands. So, if you want to use them in your text, you have two possibilities (most likely, there are even more):

- use a backslash: `\{`
- enter math mode: `${$`.